# connection pooling using prepare statement in a JAVA application

Tags: postgresql

Due the high increse of applicative connections to out PostgreSQL databases, I'm looking for a connection pooler that can handle `prepared statements`.

We already use [PgBouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/) in **session mode**, it works great for pooling our connections, but it cannot manage `prepared statements`.

I searched on the Internet to find other possible solutions. I found [PgPool-II](https://www.pgpool.net/), it has some features limiting catalog queries, but I'm not sure it can handle `prepared statements`.

> Do you know connection pooling tools that can manage `prepared statements`?

Answer (score 0):

pgbouncer can deal with [prepared statements in session pooling mode](https://www.pgbouncer.org/faq.html#how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-session-pooling).  But you have to configure "server_reset_query" if it is not already configured.

Or by "manage", do you mean something different than just "tolerate"?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes for your reply, the parameter `server_reset_query` is already set to **DISCARD ALL** as discribed in your link.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that works seamlessly with `prepared statements` and not only tolerating them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the Internet, I found this [Issue on pgbouncer github](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/203#issuecomment-302992260), explaining the complexity of managing query plan caching for PgBouncer.

One of my colleague found this [workaround](https://blog.bullgare.com/2019/06/pgbouncer-and-prepared-statements/), it looks promising and worth a test!